# Markers not working in a Nivo ResponsiveLineCanvas

Tags: javascript, nivo-react

I'm trying to switch from a `ResponsiveLine` to a `ResponsiveLineCanvas` using Javascript library [Nivo](https://nivo.rocks/) version 0.80.0 and React 18.2.0, but markers are just not shown.
Not sure what I am missing, so I created an example to reproduce the issue

https://codesandbox.io/embed/fast-leftpad-q6ypqr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

It is sufficient to switch from `ResponsiveLineCanvas` to `ResponsiveLine` and the marker get shown.

From the docs I cannot guess if the feature is unsupported in `ResponsiveLineCanvas`. So, am I missing any configuration?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ResponsiveLineCanvas } from "@nivo/line";
import { ResponsiveLine } from "@nivo/line";

const commonProperties = {
  width: 900,
  height: 400,
  margin: { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 80 },
  animate: true,
  enableSlices: "x"
};
const App = () => (
  <div style={{ height: 600 }}>
    <ResponsiveLineCanvas
      {...commonProperties}
      data={[
        {
          id: "Id of serie",
          data: [
            { x: 0, y: 0.2 },
            { x: 1, y: 0.3 },
            { x: 2, y: 0.5 },
            { x: 3, y: 0.4 },
            { x: 4, y: 0.3 },
            { x: 5, y: 0.5 },
            { x: 6, y: 0.3 },
            { x: 7, y: 0.1 }
          ]
        }
      ]}
      markers={[
        {
          axis: "x",
          value: 2,
          lineStyle: { stroke: "#6aa84f", strokeWidth: 3, opacity: 0.95 },
          legend: "Budget line"
        }
      ]}
      layers={[
        "grid",
        "axes",
        "areas",
        "lines",
        "points",
        "slices",
        "mesh",
        "legends",
        "markers"
      ]}
      enableGridX={false}
      colors={["rgb(97, 205, 187)", "rgb(244, 117, 96)"]}
      xScale={{
        type: "linear"
      }}
      yScale={{
        type: "linear",
        stacked: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 1
      }}
      enableArea={true}
      areaOpacity={1}
      enableSlices={false}
      useMesh={true}
      crosshairType="cross"
    />
  </div>
);
export default App;
```

Comment: If I hover over the chart in the `Canvas` version I get `TypeError: e.getBBox is not a function`.  I wonder if that's related, or if the component is just buggy.  PR to fix that error: https://github.com/plouc/nivo/pull/2125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it's clear that support for `markers` has not been implemented in the `LineCanvas` and `ResponsiveLineCanvas` components.  There is no mention of `markers` anywhere [in the component source](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/blob/master/packages/line/src/LineCanvas.js).  The `markers` prop is not included in the destructuring assignment so that prop will be ignored and have no effect.

As for the `layers` prop, this Canvas version goes through a bunch of `if` statements to check for known layer types.  `"marker"` is not one of these types.  There is no `else` statement that lets you know if a provided layer was invalid, it just doesn't do anything.

The supported values of the `layers` prop, [per the source code](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/blob/3e639a28bc969ded57ad881a776ad973645ecdbf/packages/line/src/LineCanvas.js#L120-L242), are:

- `"grid"`
- `"axes"`
- `"areas"`
- `"lines"`
- `"points"`
- `"mesh"`
- `"legends"`
- custom functions

On the other hand, the SVG-based `Line` and `ResponsiveLine` components *do* use the `markers` prop and support `layers=["markers"]`.  You can [see here](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/blob/3e639a28bc969ded57ad881a776ad973645ecdbf/packages/line/src/Line.js#L152-L162) how the `markers` prop is passed off to a `CartesianMarkers` component from the `@nivo/core` package and the resulting element is stored in the `layerById` dictionary.

Comment: Ok. But the SVG-based components are not supposed to be used for large plots, as per docs.

Comment: You should open an issue in their GitHub repo to request support for this feature. (Or take a stab at it yourself and submit a PR)